# How to config unique version in release

Tags: maven, version-control, continuous-deployment, parent-pom, jfrog-xray

I want to create unique release version (same as snapshot version)
I rtied to use uniqueVersion tag in the distributionManagement but it didn't help.
I using jfrog artifactory.

my pom:

```
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-release</version>

<distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshot</id>
            <name>snapshot</name>
            <url>http:/...../list/local-snapshot/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>release</id>
            <name>release</name>
            <url>http:/...../list/local-release/</url>
            <uniqueVersion>true</uniqueVersion>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "unique version"? Release versions are always unique in the sense that you can build a version like `1.2.3` only once.

Comment: No, I mean like in SNAPSHOT version, that jfrog (or maven build) add the timestamp and build number to the artifact

Comment: Release versions do not work that way. If you need a timestamp in your version (do you really?), you need to create it in Jenkins (or whatever build server you use).

Comment: But then the artifact will contain the timestamp, and in snapshot version he don't. meaning, when I will want to use the artifact I will have to use parent-1.0.0-10102020

Comment: What do you actually want to do with your timestamped release versions? Remember that a release version (like `1.0.0`) can only be built _once_.

Comment: So there is no way to build more then one release version? For example, I'm in a split time, but I still have some work to do before I can relay release my version. There is any way to use release version but handle the versions like snapshot?

Comment: Release versions are fixed. This distinguishes them from Snapshots. If you want a version you can override, use a Snapshot. If youneed a new release, build `1.0.1`, then `1.0.2` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single version (release version) lets says `1.0.0` this will be put into central repository (you might not do that but let use assume that).

So now someone starts to use your version `1.0.0`. After a time you decide to change this version `1.0.0` somehow (let us assume this would be possible). The result would be that the user of this version `1.0.0` could be faced with code changes/failing builds etc. cause you have changed your version `1.0.0`. And the end of the story would be the build which is based on version `1.0.0` is not reliable anymore.

That's the reason why releases are immutable.

This is the reason to use exact version numbers in your pom file which address exactly a single artifact in a particular version which will never change over the time.

But how to solve the issue of changes. Simply create a new release let us say `1.0.1` which fixes one or more bugs. Or `1.1.0` which adds new functionality etc.

The schema with the three digits is called [semantical versioning.](https://semver.org/)